# ServiceStack Funq MVC html helper extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack, helper, funq

I'm trying to create a MVC html helper extension that have to be declared as a static class, something like this:

```
public static class PhotoExtension
{
    public static IPhotoService PhotoService { get; set; }
    public static IGalleryService GalleryService { get; set; }

    public static MvcHtmlString Photo(this HtmlHelper helper, int photoId, string typeName)
    {
         //[LOGIC GOES HERE]
         return new MvcHtmlString(..some resulting Html...);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use IPhotoService and IGalleryService inside that `Photo()` method. So far the only way I found how to inject these services, within AppHost.Configure():

```
PhotoExtension.PhotoService = container.Resolve<IPhotoService>();
PhotoExtension.GalleryService = container.Resolve<IGalleryService>();
```

This works, though I curious whether there is some better way to achieve this.

Both `IPhotoService` and `IGalleryService` are registered the standard way in `AppHost.Configure()`.

Thanks, Antonin

Answer (score 2):

A bit easier to read/follow, wire them up in static constructor?

```
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;

public static class PhotoExtension
{
    public static IPhotoService PhotoService { get; set; }
    public static IGalleryService GalleryService { get; set; }

    static PhotoExtension()
    {
        PhotoService = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<IPhotoService>();
        GalleryService  = EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<IGalleryService>();
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Photo(this HtmlHelper helper, int photoId, string typeName)
    {
     //[LOGIC GOES HERE]
     return new MvcHtmlString(..some resulting Html...);
    }
}
```